# ¿Como obtener el texto del radio button seleccionado, jquery?

Tags: jquery

Buen día.
Tengo la siguiente lista de radio buttons:

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label class="label-radio item-content">
           <input type="radio" name="entregaPedido" value="2">
               <span class="item-media">
                <i class="icon icon-form-radio"></i>
               </span>
               <span class="item-inner">
               <span class="item-title">Recoger en Centro de Negocio</span>
                                    </span>
                                </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label class="label-radio item-content">
                                    <input type="radio" name="entregaPedido" value="1" checked>
                                    <span class="item-media">
                                        <i class="icon icon-form-radio"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="item-inner">
                                        <span class="item-title">Envío a Domicilio Normal</span>
                                    </span>
                                </label>
  </li>
  <li id="sucursalesCorreos">
    <label class="label-radio item-content">
                                    <input type="radio" name="entregaPedido" value="1">
                                    <span class="item-media">
                                        <i class="icon icon-form-radio"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="item-inner">
                                        <span class="item-title">Entregar en Sucursal de Correos</span>
                                    </span>
                                </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Y en esta función obtengo el valor del radio button seleccionado:

```
$$("#btn-4").click(function (e) {
 formaentregaPedido = $('input:radio[name=entregaPedido]:checked').val();
});
```

Pero en la función anterior quiero obtener lo que este escrito en la clase `item-title` ya que puede ser **Recoger en Centro de Negocio, Envío a Domicilio Normal o Entregar en Sucursal de Correos.**

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: como *pseudocodigo* yo haria: ya tienes el radio encontrado, no? accede a su elemento padre, y despues usa `find` para encontrar el elemento `item-title` y coges su `text()`. Intentalo y si no te sale añade tus problemas concretos siguiendo [mcve]. Un saludo !

Answer (score 1):

Con tu estructura html hice el siguiente código para obtener el texto, solo dal click al botón **"Obtener valor y texto"**:

```js
$("#obtener").click(function (e) {
  let valor =  $('input:radio[name=entregaPedido]:checked').val();
  
  let texto = $('input:radio[name=entregaPedido]:checked').parent().find(".item-title").text();
  alert("valor = "+valor+" Texto = "+texto);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
     <li>
       <label class="label-radio item-content">
       <input type="radio" name="entregaPedido" value="2">
           <span class="item-media">
            <i class="icon icon-form-radio"></i>
           </span>
           <span class="item-inner">
           <span class="item-title">Recoger en Centro de Negocio</span>
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label class="label-radio item-content">
                                <input type="radio" name="entregaPedido" value="1" checked>
                                <span class="item-media">
                                    <i class="icon icon-form-radio"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="item-inner">
                                    <span class="item-title">Envío a Domicilio Normal</span>
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li id="sucursalesCorreos">
                            <label class="label-radio item-content">
                                <input type="radio" name="entregaPedido" value="1">
                                <span class="item-media">
                                    <i class="icon icon-form-radio"></i>
                                </span>
                                <span class="item-inner">
                                    <span class="item-title">Entregar en Sucursal de Correos</span>
                                </span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    
<button id="obtener">Obtener valor y texto</button>
```